# Plot panda dataframe with multiple x and y columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I want to do a pandas dataframe plot and plot x1 with y1 and x2 with y2 in one plot. My dataframe looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'x1': [1,2,3,4,5], 'x2': [2,4,8,10,11], "y1" : [3,3,3,3,3], "y2" : [4,3,2,1,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.plot(x = "x1", y = "y1")
df.plot(x = "x2", y = "y2")
```

However, I always obtain two different plots. I tried something like

```
df.plot(x = ["x1", "x2"], y = ["y1", "y2"])
```

but I realized, that x must be a label or position. I know from Matlab a hold on solution, but I am not sure how to do it in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
ax = df.plot(x = "x1", y = "y1")
df.plot(x = "x2", y = "y2", ax=ax)
```